# How come an element selector is overriding a class selector with !important?

Tags: css, cascade, css-specificity

I was reading about [unset property at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) and then got stuck in their code example(the code below) without understanding how come an element selector is overriding a class selector with an !important declaration while being earlier in the cascade.

ps: English isn't my main language, let me know if it sounded confusing.

```css
p {
  color: red;
}

.foo {
  color: blue !important; 
}

.bar {
  color: green;
}

.bar p {
  color: unset;
}
```

```html
<p>This text is red.</p>
<div class="foo">
  <p>This text is also red.</p>
</div>
<div class="bar">
  <p>This text is green (default inherited value).</p>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no selector target a div element so where you see the override?

Comment: I'm expecting the following: the second paragraph being blue because the specificity value of class selector is bigger than an element selector, even more having an !important declaration and being later in the cascade.